# Google map v2 give zero results for routes between two points

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

In Google map v2 i am calling following url to get routes result:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=47.656,-123.360&destination=47.656,-125.360&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving

but it is giving result:

```
<DirectionsResponse><status>ZERO_RESULTS</status></DirectionsResponse>
```

Please suggest what to do i need to show these routes on map.

Comment: check it on `Google Map Official` app. possible there is no route available between this locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i personally checked it for your lat/long

```
47.656,-123.360 destination=47.656,-125.360
```

google not give any result (for the location).

reason : your source lat/long is valid but there is some some monastery or hill around there. google only provide route path where near some roads/way.
your second lat/long is not valid.

because there is problem with find the location onto these lat long.

Please try with some valid lat/long which has road near by it.

Answer (score 0):

The given orgin and destination is connecting the sea and city. Kindly give valid lat and lng pairs then check it. It will Work

Answer (score 0):

Because in those lat longs have does not possibility to draw driving route .Check on google map and try to make route between those lat long.

i have already checked it is not possible to draw driving route.